# Reading bmp image from url - R

Tags: r, rmagick

I try to read a bmp image from url. I tried:

```
library(bmp)
lenna <- read.bmp("https://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp")
```

but it sends an error message: "Error in file(f, open = "rb"): cannot open the connection to 'https://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp'"

Then I tried using magick package:

```
library(magick)
lenna <- image_read("https://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp")
```

But it returns, perhaps due to security reasons:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url) : 
  SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

Please, could you help me?

Comment: I used the codes above and they worked well. Maybe you can try updating the `curl` version.  My version is _curl_4.3_

Comment: You may disable http.sslVerify side.

Comment: Hello @maydin, my version is 4.3 too.

Comment: @ozturkib, how can I disable http.sslVerify side?

Comment: I have checked the code too. There is no issue to handle the image.

Comment: Much easier solution > could you try it with http instead of https ?

Comment: Just a question, when you mention that there is no issue handling the image, do you refer to the first (`bmp`) or second (`image_read`) function?

Comment: @ozturkib, I tried `http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp` but no success.

Comment: @Alexis if you do not put http at the beginning, it might auto-forwarded to https so it is not like that. I have placed my one at the bottom as an answer. Please try that one.

Comment: @Alexis I cannot replicate your issue. You should be informative about replication of it. Otherwise, the conversation will entirely be messy noisy :(

Answer (score 1):

I have visualised the image without any issue as below.

```
library(magick)
image_url <- "http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp"
lenna <- image_read(image_url)
print(lenna)
```

Comment: Pleasure @Alexis! As I said earlier, if I have chance to replicate the issue on my side, I might help more, but this is all at this point. Thanks for your acceptance as well.

Comment: my mistake, I opened the file from my documents and that's why I saw the image. But still can't read from url.